# Exporting multiple choice fields

Tags: custom-fields, export

Does anyone know how to export a multiple choice field into a spreadsheet in a way that filters each response into a different column?

For example, a field has options:

1. apple
2. banana
3. pineapple

A contact record has "apple" and "banana" selected for the field.

In exporting their record, I would like three columns to represent the data in the field, one column for apple, one for banana, one for pinapple.

Is there a way to do this in CiviCRM, or would I need to export and then run a script in Excel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of anything that can be done via CiviCRM UI to address this, so I think you would be better to manipulate it after exporting.